# What does "parity eigenvalue" mean in Fu-Kane formula?

Tags: topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry, topological-phase

I'm studying the online course "Topology in Condensed Matter", in the QSHE section (<https://topocondmat.org/w5_qshe/fermion_parity_pump.html>), I've studied the Fu-Kane formula

$$ Q=\Pi_{n,j} P_{n,j} \quad(n\text{ is band index, }j\text{ is TRIM index})$$

which tells us in a TR topological insulator with inversion symmetry, to compute the $Z_2$ invariant, we just need to product the "parity eigenvalues" at each time-reversal invariant momentum (TRIM).

But I'm somewhat confused with the term "parity eigenvalue", i.e. I don't understand what is the quantity $P_{n,j}$ to be computed.

For example, there is a model (where $\sigma$ denotes orbital degree of freedom and $s$ denotes spin degree of freedom)$$h(\mathbf{k})=\lambda \sigma_{z}\left[s_{x} \sin \left(k_{y}\right)-s_{y} \sin \left(k_{x}\right)\right]+\sigma_{x} (\epsilon-2 t\left[\cos \left(k_{x}\right)+\cos \left(k_{y}\right)\right])$$
which resepects both TR symmetry $(is_y \mathcal{K})$ and inversion symmetry $(\sigma_x)$. At TRIM $(k_x=0,k_y=0)$,
$$h(0,0)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & -4 t+\epsilon & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -4 t+\epsilon \\
-4 t+\epsilon & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -4 t+\epsilon & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
Then how do I compute the "parity eigenvalue" $P_{\{0,0\}}$?

And there suppose to be a topological transition from topological phase to trivial phase when $\epsilon$ changes from $\epsilon>0$ to $\epsilon<0$, how can I see this with Fu-Kane formula calculation?

Answer (score 0):

The parity eigenvalue is the eigenvalue of an electronic band with respect to inversion symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

At $\mathbf{k} = (0,0)$ the Hamiltonian can be written as
\begin{equation}
h(0,0) = \sigma_x (\epsilon - 4t).
\end{equation}
Note how this is proportional to the parity operator $h(0,0) = (\epsilon - 4t) P$. This means that energy eigenstates with positive energy will have a positive parity eigenvalue and vice-versa.

Notice that for a given state the energy will flip sign at $\epsilon = 4t$. I am not sure, but I suppose this is the point where the topological phase transition happens.